# Calculating how many iterations to make a list that doubles each iteration, n elements long

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

If I have a list of numbers starting with four numbers, the list doubles in size after each iteration, how would I calculate how  take to have a list of exactly n elements long?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After $n$ iterations, you have $4\cdot 2^n$ elements.  If you want to have $N$ elements, $N=4\cdot 2^n, \log_2 N=2+n$

Comment: could you write a simple example, it has been a long time since I have used any of this, just want to make sure I understand it.

Comment: Why don't you try calculating it for a few small values of $n$?  To solve for $n$ your calculator probably gives $\log$ to base $10$ and base $e$.  One of the laws of logarithms is $\log_2 N=\frac {\log_a N}{\log_a 2}$

Comment: I will, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence is defined by $a_0 = 4$ and $a_n = 2 a_{n-1}$ is given by
$$
a_n = 2^{n+2}, \quad n \geq 0.
$$
Solve $N = 2^{n+2}$ to get $n = \log_2 N - 2$.